# Outlook Addin VSTO - On demand expand folders

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have developed VSTO Addin using c#. In my application, I am creating PST data file.
In PST file, there is some big folder structures.so, it takes too much time. so, i want to make this structure on demand.

I done some R&D on Folder expand event. but i did not get any thing. Please help me.

if anyone of you having idea about outlook folder expand event then please do comment. otherwise please suggest how to achieve this functionality in other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  select a subfolder of the folder in question to make sure the parent folder is expanded:

```
Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = YourSubFolder
```